# Looking for a word to describe someone who has high achievements in a particular field

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a word to describe a person who has high achievements in a particular field. High achievements can be subjective so this word should have personal meanings. For example, I really like an artist, although he may not be the best artist in the world, I just personally like his work so much that he has the power to motivate me to study art and set up a goal for myself to become someone like him. so he is my . Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe he is your **role model**.

According to Wikipedia, A role model is a person who serves as an example, or whose behavior is emulated by others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a panacaea here for you. As you said, this is a "personal meaning" question. Here are some ideas though:

- **Inspirational**: Great and able to spark greatness in others
- **Accomplished**: Self-facing indication of greatness
- **Pan-talented**: Really a family of words beginning with 'pan-' emphasizing greatness accross multiple fields or disciplines
- **Supernatural**: Implication of other-worldy quality of talent; beyond what previously was thought to be human limits
- **Mythical**: The world will forever refer to this person with regard to this field from this point forward.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Okay... this is totally subjective to the subject but here goes...

If you really admire and appreciate their work just say it. If they have no formal standard of achievement standards set to their work (i.e. awards) just express how their work has affected your passion and ideas.

If they have received documentation of their achievements (awards, degrees, acclamation, or kudos) simply state, "In reference to your accolades..." or something as such.

Seriously... if you have a profound respect and appreciation for an artist of any respect use your resources to research their craft to provide the necessary data to put together a proper salutation.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that the OP's person is the **supremo** in his particular field (of art, etc.)

**Supremo:**  *British, informal:* "A person with great authority or skill in a certain area".

As in *"an interior by design* ***supremo*** *Kelly".*  (Oxford Living Dictionaries)